# jquery mobile getting the href out of the list view

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I working on a multi-page JQM app. In one of my pages, I pull in two RSS feeds and display them using the jFeed plugin.

What I'd like to do is trap the click event in a listview, grab the href and hand it to the Phonegap/Cordova ChildBrowser plugin so that it displays in the child browser.

I'm struggling with is getting the href out of the clicked event. I don't know if this is a context or precedence problem or something very simple that I'm missing.

In my included app.js file:

```
$("#chooseEvent").live('pageinit', function(event) {
  $.getFeed({
  url: "https://www1.ucsc.edu/news_events/calendar/rss/Today.ashx",
  complete: function(feed) {
  //called when complete
  //alert('complete');
  },
  success: function(feed) {
  //called when successful
  //alert('success' + feed.title);
  $("#content ul").append('<li data-role="divider" data-theme="b">' + feed.title + '</li>');
    for (var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 10; i++) {
    var item = feed.items[i];
    $("#content ul").append('<li><a href="' + item.link + +"rel=external" + '">' + item.title + '</a></li>');
  }
  // run refresh on the listview to get the theme added correctly
  $('#content ul').listview('refresh');
  },
  error: function(feed) {
  //called when there is an error
  //alert('error');
  }
  // get the item clicked and prepare it for Child Browser
  $("#content ul").on('click', function(e) {
  //var url = this.href; // outputs #
  // var url = e.target; // outputs #
  var url = $(this).attr("href"); // result is undefined
  //var url = this.parent; // result in undefined
  alert(url);
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

the html page

```
<div data-role="page" data-title="Campus Events" id="chooseEvent" addBackBtn="true">
<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
<a href="index.html" rel="external" data-icon="arrow-l"  data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="b">Back</a>
<h3>Today's Events</h3>
<a href="index.html" data-rel="back" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"  data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="b">Home</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content" id="content">
<ul data-role="listview" id="eventList" data-theme="b">

</ul>
</div> <!-- /content -->    
</div> <!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `href` in the `click` event, shouldn't you bind to the newly inserted `<li>` tags, i.e.:

```
 $("#content li").on('click', function(e) {
     ...
     ...  
 });
```

Or rather, something like:

```
$('#content ul').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    ...
    ...
});
```

Not too sure on which is better (or the difference, really).